# Azure does not see Index.cshtml

Tags: azure, web, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, deploying

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET Core application on Azure service. This works, but when I try to use the application functionality, I get the message

> Your App Service app is up and running.

Moreover, in my `wwwroot` folder I don't have any `.html` files. I only have an `Index.cshtml` file, which is located in the `Views/Home`-folder in my application, all another files are `.css`, `.js`, etc.

When I run the application in Visual Studio in Debug mode, immediately opens the page in browser that was generated from `Index.cshtml`. But after the application is published in Azure, this does not happen.

What can I do to make Azure see `Index.cshtml`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Azure or ASP.NET Core. Both dynamic and static files are supported. The templates are used for years. Post your routing, configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, a default route would be added to `Configure` method of your `Startup.cs` file as follows:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I also created my .Net Core 2.0 MVC application to check this issue, it could work as expected on local side and my azure web app.

> Moreover, in my wwwroot folder I don't have any .html files.

Views under Web Application and Web Apllication MVC would be compiled into `{your-webapplication-assemblyname}.PrecompiledViews.dll`, you could leverage [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) to check your DLLs.

For your issue, I would recommend you clear the web content in your web app via [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/), or modify the publish settings and choose **Remove additional files at destination** under File Publish Options, then redeploy your application to Azure Web App to narrow this issue.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. I really didn't configurate rooting correctly. Sorry for stupid mistake on my part!

Answer (score 1):

Are you finding index.cshtml in your web package? In case if you get index.cshtml in your final web package, you may need to add index.cshtml file type to the following in..

..YourAzureWebApp --> Application Settings --> Default Documents

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. There are two types of applications, as presented below in the picture: Web Application and Web Apllication MVC. I worked with the second type of application. When I selected the first type and published the application, Azure immediately found the required index.html. I just had to choose Web Application.

But why does not it work with the second type of application (Web Apllication MVC)? I still do not know the answer to this question.[image]

Comment: That's not the issue at all. [Static files work with both templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) - both templates use the *same* stack, ASP.NET Core,  with different configurations. Where did you place your static files in each case? What does your configuration, routing look like?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right. I, apparently, did not correctly set the routing or forgot that I made some changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

2 cents from my side as I just stuck for a while with this.

The problem was that yesterday I'd been playing around with deploying to Ubunut / Ngnix and today I decided to try Azure.

BUT I forgot to comment (disable) the following lines in my Startup:

```
//for nginx server
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
         {
           ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
          });
```

and that costed me almost half of the day to find the issue.

I also put the routing in the following way

```
    app.UseStatusCodePages();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Pages}/{action=Index}");
    });
```

Now looks like it works on Azure :)